# objective c - search within list of files

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, file, search

I want to perform a search in my iPad app, similar to searching on a desktop, where I enter a keyword and it performs a search for the word within a certain folder containing different types of files (Word, PDF, TXT, etc.). I need to do this search when the files are not open. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the name of the files you keep in your specific directory.
Take a look and try the following methods:

- enumeratorAtPath:
- contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:

Then, applies a comparator to the file names, and store the path of the files matching with your string.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMetadataQuery.

File metadata provides several application programming interfaces that allow it application to search for files based on data that is part of the file or file system. The level of interaction your application requires with the search results will often dictate the API that you chose.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001841

Comment: I don't think `NSMetadataQuery` is available on iOS for searching local files, just iCloud.